# Altair Scatter Chart

Tags: charts, altair

i am looking for a way to make a point chart based on multiple nominal conditions. i am plotting 2 values on x and y, but i would like to differentiate these points based on year as well as 'type'.

currently, the way i do it is to assign year to color while 'type' is assigned to shape

```
color=alt.condition(selection, alt.Color('Date:T'), alt.value('lightgray'), scheme='red' )
shape = alt.Shape('type:N')
```

a few questions:

1. is it possible to change the color scheme of the points instead of the default colors to say shades of red/blue/black, etc?
2. is it possible to assign one color scheme/shade (instead of shapes) to 'types'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. is it possible to change the color scheme of the points instead of the default colors to say shades of red/blue/black, etc?

Yes, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#customizing-colors. You can use any of the built-in [Vega color schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/), or define your own using the methods discussed there. From your example, it might look something like this:

```
color=alt.condition(
  selection,
  alt.Color('Date:T', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='reds')),
  alt.value('lightgray')
)
```

> 2. is it possible to assign one color scheme/shade (instead of shapes) to 'types'?

No, there is no built-in way to apply two color scales based on two fields in the data (how would a mark choose between the two colors assigned to it?) One possible approach would be to use an opacity encoding for the second field, which is reflected in the lightness of the marks. For your example, it might look like this:

```
opacity='type:N'
```

Comment: Hi Jake, thanks for the quick response. For #1, i was not able to change anything. This is what i'm trying to do: color2=alt.condition(selection, alt.Color('typex:N'), alt.value('white'), scale=alt.Scale(scheme='dark2')). but whatever i type under scheme, it doesnt change anything regardless if it were the temporal scale for Date or the Nominal ones for type. For # 2, what i meant is: for the dates, it remains to follow the color of the other field type - but applies the scaling from light to dark.

Comment: See my edited answer: I added example code snippets.

Comment: thanks Jake! it works now. driving me crazy that it goes inside color not conditions. though still not clear to me why i need to use alt.scale and scheme wont work